# Salvando arquivo no servidor

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, 
estou tentando enviar um arquivo com php para o servidor, porem não tá indo para a pasta determinada e está ficando "solto" na pasta principal.

[image: Aqui onde lista os arquivos, o TIPO é onde ele deveria ir]

[image: porém ele fica fora da pasta uploads]

E além disso, invés do arquivo ir para a pasta selecionada, ele tá pegando o nome do caminho. Exemplo: Lista.pdf 
quando upo ele muda de nome, para: painel/uploads/licitacao/

Agora segue o trecho do código onde eu indico o endereço:

```
<?php
  include "conexao.php";
  // Lista de tipos de arquivos permitidos
  $tiposPermitidos= ("application/pdf");
  //var_dump($_FILES);exit;
  // O nome original do arquivo no computador do usuário
  $arqName = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
  // O tipo mime do arquivo. Um exemplo pode ser "image/gif"
  $arqType = $_FILES['arquivo']['type'];
  // O tamanho, em bytes, do arquivo
  $arqSize = $_FILES['arquivo']['size'];
  // O nome temporário do arquivo, como foi guardado no servidor
  $arqTemp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
  // O código de erro associado a este upload de arquivo
  $arqError = $_FILES['arquivo']['error'];
  //codigo do tipo de arquivo
  $tipoArquivo = $_POST['local'];
  if ($arqError == 0) {
    // Verifica o tipo de arquivo enviado
    if ($arqType != $tiposPermitidos) {
      echo 'O tipo de arquivo enviado é inválido!';
    // Não houveram erros, move o arquivo
    }elseif ($tipoArquivo == 1) {
      $pasta = 'painel/uploads/licitacoes/1/';
      //var_dump(move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $arqName));exit;
      $upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $arqName);
    }elseif ($tipoArquivo == 2) {
      $pasta = 'painel/uploads/edital/2/';
      //var_dump(move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $arqName));exit;
      $upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $arqName);
    }elseif ($tipoArquivo == 3) {
      $pasta = 'painel/uploads/legislacao/3/';
      //var_dump(move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $arqName));exit;
      $upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $arqName);
    }   
  }
      //Verifica se o arquivo foi movido com sucesso
      if ($upload == true) {
        // Cria uma query MySQL
        $query = mysqli_query($conectar,"INSERT INTO `pdf` (`id`, `nome`, `tipo`) VALUES (NULL, '{$arqName}', '{$tipoArquivo}')");
        if ($query == true) {
          header("Location: listar_pdf.php");
        }
      }else{

        //header("Location: upload.php");
        echo 'Ocorreu algum erro com o upload, por favor tente novamente!';
      }
```

Comment: não teria que encerrar com uma / em $pasta? exemplo: $pasta = 'painel/uploads/licitacoes/1/'

Comment: quando faço isso, cai no else:            }else{

            header("Location: subir_arquivo.php");
            echo 'Ocorreu algum erro com o upload, por favor tente novamente!';
          }

Comment: 1 2 3 não são pastas? tem que finalizar com  /

Comment: Esse seu arquivo está em que pasta?

Comment: O que eu upei? está ficando na pasta "Painel", eu quero que ele fique na pasta "painel/uploads/licitacoes/

Comment: o que manda upar

Comment: No meu computador

Comment: nesse caso, lamento, não sei.